# Can't load Core Data in to-many attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

I have been unable to add and read core data attributes in a one-to-many
relationship. After reading many SO, Apple Docs and other articles I still have
not accomplished this. To make a simple test, I created a standard Master Detail
App with Core Data. This works with no issues for the main entity.

The core data relationship is as shown below.
[image]

Here is the code to place some test data into the store. Note that I am
attempting to add the to-many data as a Set for each InvItem and have made the
keywordList attribute Transformable. I thought this was the best approach, but
obviously that is not working here.

```
func seedInvItems(num : Int) {

    for index in  1...num {

        let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("InvItem", inManagedObjectContext: kAppDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! InvItem

        newManagedObject.name = "myName\(index)"
        newManagedObject.category1 = "myCategory1x\(index)"
        newManagedObject.compartment = "myCompartment\(index)"
        newManagedObject.entryDate = NSDate()

        //and for the one-to-many relationship
        var myStoreKeywordSet = Set<String>()
        myStoreKeywordSet = ["one","two","three"]

        // do an insert just for grins
        myStoreKeywordSet.insert("four")

        let newManagedObject2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("InvItemKeyword", inManagedObjectContext: kAppDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! InvItemKeyword

        newManagedObject2.keywordList = myStoreKeywordSet

    }//for in

    kAppDelegate.saveContext()

    let fetchRequestTest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "InvItem")
    let sorter : NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequestTest.sortDescriptors = [sorter]

    var resultsTest : [InvItem]?

    do {
        resultsTest = try kAppDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestTest) as? [InvItem]

        for object in resultsTest! {
            let myRetrieveKeywordSet = object.invitemkeywords
            print(myRetrieveKeywordSet)
        }//for in

    } catch let error as NSError {
        //what happens on failure
        print("And the executeFetchRequest error is \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }//do catch

}//seedInvItems
```

For completeness, I did create the NSManagedObject subclasses for the Core
Data Entities.

When running the app, the master detail for InvItem behaves as expected but I
get no storage of the to-many items.

Here is the console log (for one InvItem):

Optional(Relationship 'invitemkeywords' fault on managed object (0x7f985a62bb70)  (entity: InvItem; id: 0xd000000000700000  ; data: {
    category1 = myCategory1x3;
    compartment = myCompartment3;
    entryDate = "2016-02-09 02:10:21 +0000";
    invitemkeywords = "";
    name = myName3;
}))

Looking at the database, there is no data for the keywordList.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Xcode 7.2.1 IOS 9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the relationship from `newManagedObject` to `newManagedObject2`.  In fact, because the relationship is one-many, it is easier to set the to-one relationship:

```
newManagedObject2.invitem = newManagedObject
```

and let CoreData handle the inverse, to-many relationship.

As to the `keyWordList` not being populated, I wonder whether your SQL browser is unable to decode CoreData's NSSet?  I also wonder whether you need to have `keywordList` as an `NSSet`?  The relationship from `InvItem` is already to-many, so your model implies that each `InvItem` can have many `InvItemKeywords`, each of which holds many keywords in its `keywordList` attribute: is that what you intended?

Comment: I think you are right on all counts. I had expected that the relationship would be set by the Core Data relationship structure. I added your line of code and indeed could retrieve the data (with one issue below).

Comment: I timed out - I think you are right on all counts. I had expected that the relationship would be set by the Core Data relationship structure. I added your line of code and indeed could retrieve the data (though the code as written seems to retrieve the entire InvItem not just the keywordList ). Also you are correct on the keywordList attribute, I should just make that a string. I need one list of keywords for each InvItem, not multiple lists. And I did discover that my SQL browser is unable to see inside the Set. Thanks!